# How can I change application's image when it is in fast-app-switching in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, fast-app-switching

I want to change image that my application's screenshot when it is in background.

[image: My Application's Image in App-Switching]

I don't want to show my application's screenshot when it is in app-switching. I want to change it and put an image, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure will it work, but you can try to handle Deactivated event to draw something on the screen. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I couldn't find anything in DeactivatedEventArg :(

Comment: What do you want to find in it? Just subscribe to the event and try to draw some kind of splash screen to hide your app's screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this.

The purpose of using a screen shot of the app when the use left it is to provide appropriate context to the user.

If the data being displayed for potentially extended periods of time would impact the application (as is common with some games) then the appropriate action to take would be to take appropriate action within the app/game when the user returns to the app.

Comment: Are you sure about these answer? Because I will describe it to my boss :) and thanks for your interest.

Comment: Absolutely. It is correct. Your boss can call me if he has any problems with that answer ;)